# issue while start react native app, androidmanifest.xml cannot cannot find file specified

Tags: react-native, android-manifest

info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libc++_shared.so, libcrypto.so, libevent-2.1.so, libevent_core-2.1.so, libevent_extra-2.1.so, libfabricjni.so, libf
> b.so, libfbjni.so, libflipper.so, libfolly_runtime.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libhermes.so, libhermes_executor.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinsp
> ector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_config.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule
> _core.so, libreact_newarchdefaults.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_rende
> r_debug.so, libreact_render_element.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_moun
> ting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, li
> breact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_legacyviewmanagerinterop.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_scrollview.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_textinput.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libruntimeexecutor.so, libssl.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libyoga.so.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> 32 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 29 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Windows\System32\Acara7\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to load XML file: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Windows\System32\Acara7> cd android
PS C:\Windows\System32\Acara7\android> ./gradlew clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
PS C:\Windows\System32\Acara7\android> npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

i tried to start react native app but it keep failing bcs AndroidManifest.xml cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

Ensure your user has the necessary file permissions.
Rebuild the project with **gradlew clean** and **react-native run-android**.
Restart the development server.